# How to detect when a reaction has occured?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I currently have a Discord bot which reads information of a API that deals with a game server panel.
In this Bot there is tasks that are to start/restart/stop/kill the server. i want to give the option for the end user to react to a embed posted by a bot with a certain reaction to trigger these tasks.
The Command and embed that are posted by the bot are:

The code which currently checks which reaction has been triggered looks like this:

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then(async (sentEmbed) => {
                                sentEmbed.react("")
                                sentEmbed.react("")
                                sentEmbed.react("")
                                sentEmbed.react("❌")
                                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                                    console.log(reaction.emoji.name)
                                    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
                                };
                                const collector = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 20000});

                                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                                    Client.startServer(args[0]).then((response) => {
                                        const start_embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                            .setTitle(response)
                                            .setColor(settings.embed.color.default)
                                            .setFooter(settings.embed.footer);
                                        message.channel.send(start_embed);

                                    }).catch((error) => {
                                        message.channel.send(client.embederror(error))
                                    });
                                });
                                const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
                                    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
                                };
                                const collector2 = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter2, {time: 20000});
                                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                                    Client.restartServer(args[0]).then((response) => {
                                        const restart_embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                            .setTitle(response)
                                            .setColor(settings.embed.color.default)
                                            .setFooter(settings.embed.footer);
                                        message.channel.send(restart_embed);
                                    }).catch((error) => {
                                        message.channel.send(client.embederror(error))
                                    });
                                });
                                const filter3 = (reaction, user) => {
                                    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
                                };
                                const collector3 = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter3, {time: 30000});
                                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                                    console.log(`User Stopped There Server`);
                                });
                                const filter4 = (reaction, user) => {
                                    return reaction.emoji.name === '❌' && user.id === message.author.id;
                                };
                                const collector4 = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter4, {time: 30000});
                                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                                    console.log(`User Killed There Server`);
                                });
                            })
```

This code works for detecting the reactions onto the message, however when a user reacts with any reaction it runs all of the trigger code, so the bot posts two embeds which i have defined as what the bot should output when a reaction is triggered.

I just want the user to click one reaction, then the bot does something, then the use can click another and the bot does something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First beautify your code, second why do you have 4 filters and reaction collectors? Just have one filter that accepts all 4 emojis and requires the user.id to be msg.author.id, and then on the collector you would check what the emoji name is, and use a switch/if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was you used `collector.on("collect")` 4 times instead of using `collector2`, `collector3` and `collector4`

It's best not to have variables like that since like it shows you might get confused

Plus you should not have 4 different filters and collectors, especially since you repeat a lot of the code

```js
const validEmojis = ['', '', '', '❌'];

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return validEmojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 20000, maxEmojis: 1 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  const name = reaction.emoji.name;
  //you only use it in two cases but I assume you will use it for all later on
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(settings.embed.color.default)
    .setFooter(settings.embed.footer);

  if (name === '' || name === '') {
    const method = name === '' ? "startServer" : "restartServer";
    Client[method](args[0])
      .then(response => {
        embed.setTitle(response);
        message.channel.send(start_embed);
      }).catch((error) => {
        message.channel.send(client.embederror(error))
      });
  } else if (name === '') {
    console.log(`User Stopped There Server`);
  } else if (name === '❌') {
    console.log(`User Killed There Server`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked great, will that only accept the reactions from the original author of the command? or will anyone be able to react and it would work?

Comment: Only accepts reactions from original author, `&& user.id === message.author.id`